# I am having trouble proving this ,$\int^{\infty}_0 x^n e^{-cx} dx = \frac{n!}{c^{n+1}}$.

Tags: integration, actuarial-science

To be more precise, $n$ is a nonnegative integer and c is a positive constant.

$\int^{\infty}_0 x^n e^{-cx} dx = \frac{n!}{c^{n+1}}$

supposedly, but I cannot prove it.

I've tried integration by parts, but can someone give me a clue ?

Comment: Use mathematical induction

Comment: As a minor matter of strategy, I would let $cx=t$. The integral is then $\frac{1}{c^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\,dx$. Then use integration by parts to get a recurrence.

Comment: Thank you, you guys are really generous and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Let  $$I_n=\int^{\infty}_0 x^n e^{-cx} dx$$

Using [LIATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) rule for Integration by Parts,

$$=x^n\int^{\infty}_0e^{-cx} dx-\int^{\infty}_0\left(\frac{d x^n}{dx}\cdot \int e^{-cx} dx\right)dx$$

$$=x^n\frac{e^{-cx}}{-c}\big|_0^{\infty}+\frac nc\int^{\infty}_0x^{n-1}e^{-cx}dx=\frac ncI_{n-1} $$

Now, $$I_0=\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-cx} dx=\frac1c$$

Comment: On your third line, you have $x^{n-2}$ when it should be $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: @AndrewD, thanks for your observation, sorry for the typo

Comment: Thank you. I will try to reprove this on my own later. I never knew that there was such a thing as LIATE rule.